# Left shifting a Python integer yielding incorrect result

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, bit-shift

Can anyone explain how this Python code:

```
print "bits_received:", bits_received
tmp = 0
print type(tmp)
tmp = (1 << bits_received)
print type(tmp)
print "tmp: 0x{:X}".format(tmp)
```

could produce this result:

```
bits_received: 95
<type 'int'>
<type 'numpy.int64'>
tmp: 0x80000000
```

Comment: `bits_received` is a NumPy scalar. NumPy integers are fixed-width, like C. It seems like NumPy is giving you the underlying C compiler's left shift behavior (which will probably be the underlying machine's left shift behavior) instead of raising an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2357112 is correct:

```
bits_received: 88 <type 'int'>
bits_received: 95 <type 'numpy.int64'>
```

The *bits_received* variable was getting its type changed from *int* to *numpy.int64*, via addition with another variable of type *numpy.int64*. Wrapping that other variable in "int(...)" solved my problem.

Thanks, user2357112!